# How to import Datasources in grafana using from the export json file

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

1)I have exported a dashboard in a json file.

2)When I re-import the json file, grafana does not install the plugins that were used in
the dashboard.

Is there a way I can configure  plugons to be insalled by default in my .ini file.
or is there a way out when I import the grafana dashboards , it also installs plugins used in the dashboards ,by default.

Answer (score 0):

No, Grafana doesn't install plugins used in the dashboard - that will be very dangerous feature. It is a Grafana admin responsibility to install plugins in advance. Also plugins can't be installed from ini file.

You can use plugin provisioning eventually - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#plugins